# Is it possible to exit a case in Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table named ABC:

```
Col Val 
a   1
b   3
c   2
a   3
b   6
c   7
a   5
b   9
c   9
a   7
b   2
c   8

SELECT MAX(CASE
WHEN COL = 'a'
THEN VAL
(exit_command_if_there_s_any)
WHEN COL = 'b'
THEN VAL*3
ELSE
VAL*4
END) AS "MAX_VAL"
FROM ABC;
```

Basically what I want is this query to return the maximum value of COL = 'a' if it exists in table else it should return the max of other COL. 
But if COL = 'a' is there, it should not check for other values in COL and should simply exit the CASE.

Comment: What is the `*3` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you've asked for -
A single max value, with precedence to`a`, `b` and then other values, multiplied by the corresponding value (none / 3 / 4).

```
select  coalesce
        (
            max(case when COL = 'a' then val end)
           ,max(case when COL = 'b' then val end) * 3
           ,max(val) * 4

        ) as "MAX_VAL"

from    ABC
```

---

```
+---------+
| MAX_VAL |
+---------+
|       7 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum value, then don't think `case`.  Instead:

```
SELECT abc.*
FROM ABC
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COL = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         VAL DESC;
```

Or, put the two values in the same column:

```
select max(case when col = 'A' then val end) as max_a,
       max(case when col = 'B' then 3 * val end) as max_3b
from abc;
```